# Open File Dialog showing HELP button

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have created a script to show Open File Dialog on clicking one button. It doesn't get invoked when I run through PowerShell console.
To solve this, I introduced an expression "$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $True" in my function as shown below:

```
function BrowseFile  
{  
$openFileDialog = New-Object windows.forms.openfiledialog  
$openFileDialog.initialDirectory = [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()  
$openFileDialog.title = "Select Changed File"  
$openFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"  
$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $True  
$openFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null   
return $openFileDialog.filename  
}
```

It fixes my problem but It displays a "HELP" button on Open File Dialog which does nothing.

I want to get rid of this HELP button or other way to display Open file Dialog.
I am running this on Win7 platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. This is a bug in the powershell console. The Powershell console (based on conhost.exe) only supports the old filedialog that includes the Help button.

In ISE you can use `$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $false`, but in a normal console it will cause the powershell process to lock/freeze. Because of this, you have to use `$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $True` like you do now.

The property is also "lying" to you, because even when it set to `$false`, it will give you a help button. It uses the "modern" filedialog which also has a help button in the form of a small blue icon in the top.

Comment: I was also thinking same but wanted confirmation from an expert. Thanks for your response. But one query, do u have any link of Microsoft where this issue is metioned?

Comment: No. AFAIK Microsoft has never made an official comment about i, but it's a known bug.